# Determining pump dimension based on Desired output

Tags: fluid-mechanics

In the following system, there is a required constant outflow at point D and F with pressure compensating drippers.

The question is how to determine the pump or at least minimum pump pressured/flow rate to compensate for the energy losses resulting from the pipe and bend and T split at point C. The flowing liquid is water at density of $1000\space kg/m^3$ and dynamic viscosity of $\mu = 890\cdot10^{-6}$ and $P_D = P_F = 1\ atm$ 
[image]

what I tried was the following

$Q_C = Q_D + Q_F = 20\space l/s$

$A = \pi D^2 \div 4 = 0,00011304\space m^3$

Now the question is if I want to calculate the pressure drop from the pipe to $Q_D$ I can write:

$\frac{P_A}{\rho} + \frac{v_A^2}{2} = \frac{P_D}{\rho} + \frac{v_D^2}{2} + \Delta P_V$

where:

$\Delta P_V = \frac{\rho}{2}\cdot [\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}{\zeta _i\cdot v_i^{-2}} + \sum_{j=1}^{j=k}{\frac{\lambda _j \cdot l_j}{d_j} \cdot v_j^{-2}} ]$

Now to calculate this I need to calculate the average flow speed at each pipe section.

My questions are:

1. Is it acceptable to calculate flow speed for each section using
   $v_{section} = Q_{section} \div A$ and if so do I need to
   recalculate this after the initial assumption to get a more accurate
   result?
2. If I need to do multiple iteration of calculation assuming I have
   already calculated  $\Delta P_{CD}$ and I know the $v_D$, how can I
   calculate the $v_C$ to find out the flow speed difference between
   these two points?
3. If possible perform a example calculation (even without
   numbers)?
4. What free software is available for students to simulate/calculate
   such pipe networks?

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/55661/10902

Comment: you reffering me to my own post ? i wouldnt have asked a new question if the answer from previous one was clear